# Entity name error

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm working on a Java desktop which is distributed via a JAR file and that JAR contains everything the application needs.  The application that generates an HTML report for various things by first generating an XML file, and then using an XSL file to convert the XML to HTML.  Once the report is generated it needs to be one file, so any script I want to use I have to include in the file, and I want to use jQuery.  I have a jQuery file in a resources folder and I can parse through it and add it to the XML file just fine, but when it is time to transform the XML into HTML via the XSL I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  'The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
ERROR:  'com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.'
```

Reading up on the error I can see that I need to encode special characters, but I'm not prepared to manually encode the entire jQuery file.

So my end goal is this:

1.) Need to have the following in my HTML report:

```
<script>
// the entire jQuery library
</script>
```

2.) My main application must be completely contained in one JAR file

3.) I would like to NOT copy/paste the jQuery library into the XSL file.  This works, but it seems sloppy.

**UPDATE #1:**

I was wrong on point 3 above.  I cannot copy/paste the jQuery library into the XSL file without getting the error:

```
java.io.UTFDataFormatException: encoded string too long: 239677 bytes
```

which is immediately followed by the more comical error:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: This Templates does not contain a class with the name 'GregorSamsa'.
```

GregorSamsa in [The Metamorphosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Metamorphosis)

**UPDATE #2:**

The start of my XSL stylesheet reads like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

    <xsl:output method="html"/>
```

I changed the version number from a `1.0` to a `2.0` but I get an error that reads:

```
ERROR:  'Unsupported XSL element 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform:sequence''
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported XSL element 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform:sequence'
```

Additionally, my jQuery file is in the same location as my XSL stylesheet, so I think the following should work (but it doesn't):

```
<xsl:sequence select="unparsed-text('jquery-1.8.3.min.js')" />
```

**UPDATE #3:**

Downloaded Saxon for Java [here](http://www.saxonica.com/download/download_page.xml) and added the JAR file to my application.  Change my call to transformer factory to this:

```
TransformerFactory f = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl(); // was TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer t = f.newTransformer( new StreamSource( Example.class.getResourceAsStream( "resource/report_style.xsl" ) ) );
Source s = new StreamSource( XMLFile );
Result r = new StreamResult( HTMLFile );
t.transform( s, r );
```

Using the suggested `<xsl:sequence select="unparsed-text('jquery-1.8.3.min.js')" />` I still get the equivalent of my original error, though now with Saxon parser:

```
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
```

**UPDATE #4:**

I wasn't getting anywhere with this so I ended up reading the HTML file back in after I had created it, added my JavaScript to it, then wrote it back out.  This is an extra step, but any difference in report generation time is imperceivable and it works.  I would still be interested to know why XSLT 2.0 wasn't solving this for me though.

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0, or are you restricted to 1.0?

Comment: @LarsH I'm using XSL 1.0 right now, but I don't think I'm "restricted" to only that.  I tried your solution but still having issues.  See `UPDATE #2`.

Comment: In order to fix #2, you'll need to make sure you're using an XSLT 2.0-capable XSLT processor. E.g. Saxon-HE (http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/). And then change the version number to 2.0 again.

Comment: @LarsH Included the Saxon JAR in my project and still get essentially the same error :(  See `UPDATE #3`.

Comment: Strange ... I wonder why. Can you show us more of the XSLT context around the `<xsl:sequence>`?

Comment: Hopefully @MichaelKay or somebody will notice this question and deliver a definitive answer regarding the parse error.

Comment: I tested this with Saxon PE 9.4.0.4, and it worked just fine - no errors. In other words, I can't reproduce the error you're seeing. If you'd like further help, please provide a reproducible test case.

Comment: If I get some time I will.  XSLT 2.0 would likely make my life easier, but right now I must press forward :/

Comment: Understood. XSLT 2.0 really is worth your while if you do any significant work with XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use XSLT 2.0, you could try

```
<script>
  <xsl:sequence select="unparsed-text('path/to/jqueryvNN.js')" />
</script>
```

That should copy in the jquery library definitions as text, and output them as appropriate in HTML. You are using the HTML output method, right? It would also be a good idea to use `cdata-section-elements="script"` (documented [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization/#XML_CDATA-SECTION-ELEMENTS)) to induce XSLT to serialize the javascript in a more efficient and more human-readable way. (Not that it will be very human-readable anyway, if you're using the standard minified version of the library.)

Since XSLT doesn't need to parse the js file, you won't have complaints about unescaped ampersands and so on.